# wp_pagenavi не переключает страницы

Tags: wordpress

Мне нужен блок, в котором будут выводится совершенно все посты с постраничной навигацией и который будет выводится НА ВСЕХ СТРАНИЦАХ.

На главной всё отлично работает, а при переходе на новость (single.php) пагинация не работает (выводится, но не переключает страницы). Я создал этот блок в sidebar.php:

```
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'paged' => $paged,
    );

    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($post_query->have_posts() ) {        

        while($post_query->have_posts() ) {

            $post_query->the_post();
    ?>

    <div class="post">
        <small class="post-time"><?php the_time('d.m.Y'); ?></small>
        <a class="post-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>

    <?php
        }
        //Пагинация
        wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $post_query ) );
    }
```

Пробовал добавлять wp_reset_postdata(), wp_reset_query() и до, и после wp_pagenavi(). Не помогло.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было всего лишь добавить эту строчку в `functions.php`:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```